# Why React Route not direct to new decided page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Why doesn't it display? SasASasaSasASasSASAasASSAsASasSAsASa

Comment: `<Rute exact path="/ItemDetail/:id" component={ItemDetail}></Rute>` is this a typo in your project, or just a copy paste mistake?

Comment: @SinanYaman OP is importing Route as Rute for some reason, so it's correct (if weird).

Comment: im new in react js :(

Comment: It's hard to tell what your application is supposed to do in the end.

Comment: @AKX pls help :( can i contact u?

Answer (score 0):

You're not ever linking to `/ItemDetail/XYZ` (where XYZ would be an ID); all you have is a link to `/ItemDetail/` (which is not declared in any `<Route />`).

(Also, it's unlikely that a `ItemSummary` component (which I assume is not a very top-level component in your app) should contain the router. The router is in general in an `<App />` sort of component, and decides which components to display (e.g. a product list page, a product detail page, etc.))

Comment: can u help edit my code? i share it in sandbox

Comment: i dont understand well

Comment: i already add /itemDetail/:id but it display at the same page not blank page

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind (there could be other things off too, but we'll know after we fix these). Your `App.js` file isn't using the correct component. Explanation below:

1. You cannot have two default exports in one `.js` or `.jsx` file.

- Create a new component for `ItemSummaryail`. Place this component in a new file, then import it in this file, and use it here.
- or you can just create a component `function ItemSummaryail () {...}` in this file and export it (if you need to use it in other files) but don't make it the default export.

2. I'm not sure what syntax this is below. `export default ItemSummaryail/"}>`. This seems to be incorrect. Create a component and put this logic in that component like you did with `ItemSummary`. Something like `function ItemSummaryail () {...}`
3. keep `export default ItemSummary`. That should be the only default export in this file
4. From an architectural standpoint, I'd suggest, if you want to avoid weird bugs, you should have all your routes and BrowserRouter logic live in `App.js` file and use `Link` to get to those routes inside child components. Unless your app is complex and needs this logic in child components, which doesn't seem to be the case yet for you.

The suggestions above except 4) are for the piece of code below:

```
export default ItemSummaryail/"}>
              <img
                alt=""
                className="downSlideImage"
                src={props.img}
              />
              <div className="downSlideTitle">{props.name}</div>
              <div className="downSlidePrice">{props.price}</div>
            </Link>
          </div>
          <Rute
            exact
            path="/ItemDetail/:id"
            component={ItemDetail}
          ></Rute>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}

export default ItemSummary;
```

Suggestion 4) is suggestion for the overall architecture of your frontend

Answer (score 0):

From My Understanding, I have given like a template that you can follow for linking/routing.

My Approach: http://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-gareth-wq8e3

Note: There can be only one default export. If you have multiple functions or classes, try creating individual files (SOC - Separation of Concern) or follow the named exports approach.